# Python: How to dynamically display image in label widget (tkinter)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am stuck trying to dynamically display a specific image on a tk page based on button clicked on a previous page. PageOne has 5 images with 5 buttons below each. Clicking on specific button should take the user to the second page and display image 3 if the 3rd button is clicked.

I have figured out how to pass a value of 1 to 5 depending on which button is clicked, and the images are saved pic1.gif,...pic5.gif so to return the correct image I just need to append the value to the file location.

I am struggling to figure out how to refresh PageTwo when it is accessed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
TITLE_FONT = ("Helvetica", 18, "bold")
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        self.attributes("-fullscreen", False)
        self.geometry('{}x{}'.format(1000, 1000))
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


        self.frames = {}
        for F in (PageOne, PageTwo):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(PageOne)

    def show_frame(self, c):
        frame = self.frames[c]
        frame.tkraise()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    praiseid = 0
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        def PraiseClick(button_id):

            PageOne.praiseid = button_id
            controller.show_frame(PageTwo)

        users= [1,2,3,4,5]

        for i in users:
            location = str('C:/Users/XXXXXXX/Documents/pic'+str(i)+'.gif')
            icon = tk.PhotoImage(file=location)
            IDlabel = tk.Label(self,image=icon)
            IDlabel.image = icon
            IDlabel.place(x=i*100,y=200,width=100,height=100)

        for j in users:
            praisebutton = tk.Button(self,text="Click",width=10,command=lambda x=j: PraiseClick(int(x)))
            praisebutton.place(x=j*100,y=300,width=100,height=44)

        backbutton = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Start Page", 
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        backbutton.place(x=100,y=50,width=200,height=44)

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def get_id(self):
        return(PageOne.praiseid)

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)


        self.location = 'C:/Users/XXXXXXX/Documents/pic'+str(self.get_id())+'.gif'
        icon = tk.PhotoImage(file=self.location)
        self.IDlabel = tk.Label(self,image=icon)
        self.IDlabel.image = icon
        self.IDlabel.place(x=0,y=200,width=100,height=100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selected image from the `PageOne` is not drawn on the `PageTwo` because the drawing function is localized in the `__init__()` function and no event is raise when the `PageTwo` is redraw by calling the function `tkraise()`.

**Problem 1** - generate an event when calling `tkraise()` of the `PageTwo`.

> Here, the OOP of Python will be the answer by overriding the function
>   `tkraise()` in the `class PageTwo`.

```
class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
...
    def tkraise(self):
        print('PageTwo.tkraise()')
        tk.Frame.tkraise(self)
        #  then call the drawing icon
        self.refresh_icon() #  see Problem 2
```

**Problem 2** - localize the drawing of the icon in a function of the `class PageTwo`.

> To take into account of the new selected icon, create a function
>   `refresh_icon()` in the `class PageTwo` and call it from both
>   `__init__()` and `tkraise()` functions.

```
class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
...
    def refresh_icon(self):
        self.location = 'C:/Users/XXXXXXX/Documents/pic'+str(self.get_id())+'.gif'
        icon = tk.PhotoImage(file=self.location)
        self.IDlabel = tk.Label(self,image=icon)
        self.IDlabel.image = icon
        self.IDlabel.place(x=0,y=200,width=100,height=100)
```

Add at the end of the `__init__()` function.

```
class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
...
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        ...
        self.refresh_icon()
```

**Bonus 1** - to prevent an Exception in case of missing image, add a check before.

> Create a `file_exists()` function, then check before loading in
>   `PhotoImage()`.

def file_exists(filepath):
    try:
        fp_file = open(filepath)
        return (True)
    except IOError:
        return (False)

And in the function `refresh_icon()` of the `class PageTwo`:

```
    self.location = 'C:/Users/XXXXXXX/Documents/pic'+str(self.get_id())+'.gif'
    if (file_exists(self.location)):
        icon = tk.PhotoImage(file=self.location)
        ...
```

**Bonus 2** - clear the current `IDlabel` in case of image not loaded.

> when creating a new `Label` in the `PageTwo`, the variable
>   `self.IDlabel` will store the new Image without deleting the old one.
>   Before creating a new one, call the `destroy()` function.

Add a declaration of the variable `self.IDlabel` and assign it to `None` in the `__init__()` function. Then call `destroy()` in the

```
class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
...
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        ...
        self.refresh_icon()
        self.IDlabel = None
...
    def refresh_icon(self):
        self.location = 'C:/Users/XXXXXXX/Documents/pic'+str(self.get_id())+'.gif'
        if (self.IDlabel): # check label and destroy it
            self.IDlabel.destroy()
        if (file_exists(self.location)):
            ...
```